# System.out.println without printing to file when using " > filename"

Tags: java, bash, shell, command-line, redirectstandardoutput

I have a peculiar problem.  I have a Java program that is run with the command :

```
cat input_file_name | ./script_name > file_output_name
```

the `script_name` script just does : `java myprogram`

My question is : how can I print out something in the console without it being "put in the file_output_name file" (since the `> file` puts all `System.out.prints` in that file)

I know this is possible because there are some already that come from some class in a library that I'm using from my java program.  However I can't find the exact source of those prints so I don't know how it is coded.

Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way is to use `System.err.println()` instead of `System.out`.

It will go to a different "device" (stderr instead of stdout), and it won't be redirected.

Answer (score 2):

The simple answer is to write those messages to `System.err` rather than `System.out`.

This will work since `>` redirects standard output but not standard error.  (You can redirect standard error, but the shell syntax is different; e.g. `foo 2> /tmp/somefile`.)

A more complicated alternative is to change your program so that it can be called with the name of the output file as an argument.  Then open the file, wrap it in a `PrintWriter` and write to that stream rather than `System.out`.  With a bit of refactoring, you should be able to structure your program so that it can be used either way.

Answer (score 1):

With what you've shown, you're only redirecting the standard out (stdout).  You can write something to the standard error (stderr) instead to have it show on the console yet.  In Java, this can be done by `System.err.println(...)`, and related methods.

Answer (score 0):

Notice that if a Java program writes to standard output, it can't control *where* does its output get redirected, that depends on how the program is invoked from the command line.

Having that clear, you can redirect the program's standard output *only* to the console, by simply removing the `> file_output_name` part from the command.

Or, you can redirect the output of the program to both the console *and* a file by using the `tee` command, take a look at this [article](http://www.skorks.com/2009/09/using-bash-to-output-to-screen-and-file-at-the-same-time/) which explains in detail how to do it.